# Issues with newfloat, custom ref macros, and listof

Tags: tocloft, newfloat

I have written macros to generate "names spaces" for chapters and sections etc. This all works great but newfloat's listof feature (or the underling tocloft) seams to break on it:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{newfloat}

%section magic
\expandafter\providecommand\csname usr@chapterlabel\endcsname[0]{}
\newcommand{\locallabel}[2][]{\label{#1:\csname usr@chapterlabel\endcsname:#2}}
\newcommand{\localref}[2][]{\ref{#1:\csname usr@chapterlabel\endcsname:#2}}


\newcommand{\smartchapter}[2][]{%
\chapter{#2}%
\label{c:#1}%
\expandafter\renewcommand\csname usr@chapterlabel\endcsname[0]{#1}%
}

% Setup new float env
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name=Test,listname={List of Tests}]{testfloat}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftestfloats

\smartchapter[a]{A chapter using localref}
In this chapter we show content A (\localref[test]{a}) and content B (\localref[test]{b}) using localref.

\begin{testfloat}
Content A
\caption{Here is a caption for A}
\locallabel[test]{a}
\end{testfloat}

\begin{testfloat}
Content B
\caption{A caption with a localref to \localref[test]{a} which can be written as a normal ref like so \ref{test:a:a}}
\locallabel[test]{b}
\end{testfloat}
\end{document}
```

In my main document all of the `localref` work. However in the `listoftestfloats` the entry for Content B is typeset as:

```
A caption with a localref to ?? which can be written as a normal ref like so 1.1
```

Where in the caption it is typeset correctly as:

```
A caption with a localref to 1.1 which can be written as a normal ref like so 1.1
```

Further I get a warning:

```
(/compile/output.lotestfloat
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 2.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `test::a' on page 2 undefined on input line 3.

)
\tf@lotestfloat=\write5
\openout5 = `output.lotestfloat'
```

So clearly it is trying to evaluate the `localref` in some context outside of the chapter (this is clear as `test::a` would be the result of `\localref[test]{a}` when `usr@chapterlabel` is empty).  I haven't been able to figure out a workaround for this.

Comment: try `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\localref}{O{}m}{\ref{#1:\csname usr@chapterlabel\endcsname:#2}}`

Comment: This works thanks! Can you give me any hint of what's going with it?